# Insert using java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a client

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "cl_id")
private Long clId;

@JoinColumn(name = "vl_id", referencedColumnName = "vl_id")
@ManyToOne
private City cityId;
```

Whenever I create a new client this way:

```
Client c = new Client();
c.setCityId(new City());
```

and persist it. The city isn't persisted also if it doesn't exist. 
Wouldn't the city be persisted also unless the City object has got an Id ?

Comment: The last two statements seem to contradict each other. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's just the variable that has a weired name. SetCityId() take a city as a parameter. It can take an already persisted city or a fresh one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable [cascading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading) :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "vl_id", referencedColumnName = "vl_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private City cityId;
```